# Can member variable and local method variable have the same name?

Tags: java, variables, syntax

How would I accomplish this?

```
class Test {
    private int var1;

    public Test(int var1) {
        var1 = var1; //set the member variable to what was passed in
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's a very obvious answer.  It's just escaping me right now.

Comment: Have a look at some good code. You'll see that exactly this (`this.x = x`) gets used for setters and constructors. There's no point in inventing a new name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, they can share the same name.  However, to reference the instance variable, you need to use the `this` prefix:

```
public Test(int var1) {
    this.var1 = var1;
}
```

Comment: So "this" is normally optional?  But in this case, I need it since the names conflict?  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: In this case, you don't need it *because* the names conflict, you need it to tell the JVM to get the reference from a different (specific) scope. "super." works similarly, but gets the variable/method from the class you're extending (an even "bigger" scope). Some languages would even offer a "global." type modifier, but not Java.

Comment: @Dolph - good explanation.  It will happily compile and run with the `var1 = var1` and later on you'd end up with a 0 value where you didn't expect one or a `NullPointerException` if `var1` is an object.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, but local variable will hide the class variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, We can. but just "can". it's not good.

Comment: -1 "it's not good" is not helpful. Besides, there are common patterns where this *is* "good."

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your answer?