# java not saving ints correctly

Tags: java

this program is for Java. it its suposed to do the Collatz conjecture. in my ming the code should work but when i enter 7 it prints out a bunch of 22's i think its a problem with java saving ints.

```
import java.util.*;
//If n is even, divide it by 2 to get n / 2. If n is odd, multiply it by 3  .    and add 1
public class infNum {
   private int num;
   private int n;
   private String comma = ", ";

   public void start() {
      System.out.println("enter a number");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      int n = keyboard.nextInt();
      num = n;
   }
   public void testEvenOdd() {
       if((num % 2) == 0) {
          ifEven(num);
      } else {
         ifOdd(num);
      }
   }

     public void ifEven(int num) {
      if(num == 1) {
         return;
      } else {
         num = num / 2;
         System.out.print(num + comma);
         testEvenOdd();
      }
   }

   public void ifOdd(int num) {
      if(num == 1) {
         return;
      } else {
         num = (num * 3) +1;
         System.out.print(num + comma);
         testEvenOdd();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, `7` is an odd number. And `7 * 3` is 21, and `21 + 1` **is** `22`. Looks like your program did exactly what you told it to.

Comment: how is this called? where is the beginning method, if it is start, none of the other methods get called?

Comment: It's more a problem of your `testEvenOdd` method checking the `num` instance variable, and your other methods never updating it.  Currently they only update their own parameter, which goes out of scope when the method ends.

Comment: Tip: `num` in your `ifEven` and `ifOdd` methods refer to the **local variable** `num` passed as parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Can member variable and local method variable have the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812290/java-can-member-variable-and-local-method-variable-have-the-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

> the code should work but when i enter 7 it prints out a bunch of
>   22's i think its a problem with java saving ints.

The problem seems to be that you're mixing instance variables with local variables `i.e` you want to update the instance variable but rather you updated the local variables. This is easy to solve, just use the `this` keyword to distinguish them.

Example:

```
import java.util.*;
    //If n is even, divide it by 2 to get n / 2. If n is odd, multiply it by 3  .    and add 1
    public class infNum {
       private int num;
       private int n;
       private String comma = ", ";

   public void start() {
      System.out.println("enter a number");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      int n = keyboard.nextInt();
      this.num = n;
   }
   public void testEvenOdd() {
       if((this.num % 2) == 0) {
          ifEven(this.num);
      } else {
         ifOdd(this.num);
      }
   }

     public void ifEven() {
      if(this.num == 1) {
         return;
      } else {
         this.num = this.num / 2;
         System.out.print(this.num + comma);
         testEvenOdd();
      }
   }

   public void ifOdd() {
      if(this.num == 1) {
         return;
      } else {
         this.num = (this.num * 3) +1;
         System.out.print(this.num + comma);
         testEvenOdd();
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated your method parameters because since instance variables are used, there is no need to pass `num` as parameter to `ifEven` and `ifOdd`. This will remove the error you're currently having. Also, note that since we no longer have method parameters with the same name as the instance variable(s), we don't need the `this` keyword any longer. However, I have left them there for good practice.

Comment: Playing devils advocate, why pass `int num` to those methods to begin with?

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw Since instance variables are used, there is no need to pass `num` as parameter to `ifEven` and `ifOdd` (I think this is what Elliott was telling too)

Comment: @BackSlash CORRECT I see where he is getting at. I should update my answer to accommodate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is 7, 22 is the correct output!

testEvenOdd() goes to the else statement, which is ifOdd(7). Here, since 7 is not 1, you are printing (7 * 3) + 1 = 22. You are then calling testEvenOdd() again! Hence, it is going to ifOdd(7), printing out 22, and calling testEvenOdd() again. It is most likely repeating indefinitely until you run out memory.

Answer (score 0):

In which order are you calling those methods? I'm gonna suppose you're calling `start()` and then `testEvenOdd()`

If you enter 7, inside the method `testEvenOdd` the `if((num % 2) == 0)` will be false (because `7 % 2` is 1). So it'll call method `ifOdd()`

Inside `ifOdd` method, as `num` is 7, the `if(num == 1)` will be false and it'll call the `else` clause: `num = (num * 3) +1`, so `num` will be 22 -> the result of (7 * 3) + 1