# how to Call a method in another Class which returns an Array list and Access the Elements in that Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am storing user data into an ArrayList and trying to access the elements from another class.

In this code I am receiving user data from my Methods class and storing them in variables and then adding those variables into another ArrayList called Userlist. I'm sending that list to the method Userdata which returns the Userlist. The method's access modifier is public so that I can access the list from any class. But I am unable to get the list from another class I don't know if there is a logical mistake.

```
attributes attri=new attributes();
attri.Email=va;
attri.Password=password;

m.Userdata(attri);
UserNameFirst=m.list.get(0);
UserLastName=m.list.get(1);
Partnerid=m.list.get(2);
Bussinessid=m.list.get(3);

txtUserName.setText(UserNameFirst+UserLastName);
txtBussinessid.setText(Bussinessid);
txtPartnerid.setText(Partnerid);

UserList.add(Partnerid);
UserList.add(Bussinessid);

UserData(UserList);
```

Method UserData code is

```
public ArrayList<String> UseData(ArrayList<String> UserList){
    return UserList;
}
```

from the class i am trying to access User list code is

```
frmLocalUser frm=new frmLocalUser();
if (frm.UseData() {
    frm.UserList.get(0);
    frm.UserList.get(1);
}
```

I am having an error in calling the `UserData` Method in `Localuser` frame.
Any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: It may help others understand your question if you provide the source for the whole class and not just portions of it. It appears you have many issues.

Comment: I have fixed your indentation and a few other issues. Please take more care when you write a question in future :)

Comment: difficult to understand from current description please provide more details

Comment: Please copy the error statement here

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the method `UseData` takes a parameter called `UserList` and simply returns the list it was given:

```
public ArrayList<String> UseData(ArrayList<String> UserList){
    return UserList; // ----------------------------^
}
```

The parameter `UserList` will [hide any fields with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812290/can-member-variable-and-local-method-variable-have-the-same-name). I can't see your class definition, but I presume you want to return the field.

This method should not require any parameters. You can change it to:

```
public ArrayList<String> UseData(){
    return UserList;
}
```

You also have a syntax error here:

```
if (frm.UseData() {
```

because you need an extra closing bracket:

```
 if (frm.UseData()) {
```

---

Also note that methods and variables should [begin with a lowercase character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) by convention.